# override parameter of anohter bundle

Tags: symfony

I'm building a bundle, which depends on another bundle. The parent bundle loads a services.yml file, which defines some parameters:

```
parameters:
    xbundle.doctrine.factory: Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory
services:
    ....
```

I know the **xbundle.doctrine.factory** parameter can be changed from **app/config/config.yml**, but I want to change its value the from within my custom child bundle. I [read the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/index.html), and also the suggested stackoverflow questions, but still can't figure how to achieve it.

Comment: I don't have an example handy but I suspect you need a compiler pass: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html.  However, don't try to override the default doctrine repository factory unless you really really really know what you are doing.  More than likely you can use doctrine event listeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must write a CompilerPass in your child Bundle, and change the value:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {  
        $container->setParameter('xbundle.doctrine.factory', '..New Value ...');
    }
}
```

Some documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration).